# How can I add the ability to extract and post tweets onto the site when user submits link?

Tags: javascript, twitter

I'm making a rails application, I want users to post their tweets by submitting a link [of the tweet]. I'm guessing its done with javascript/twittera api. Things needed to be extracted:

- tweet owner
- tweet + image
- link to user profile page

Comment: By submitting what link? From your list of things that needs to be extracted, it is a link to their "tweet". Is this right?

Comment: Also, SO questions must be about specific problem unit, not a "guide" to develop something. Please read [the guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I thought it was obvious, yes a link of the tweet.

Answer (score 0):

[Twitter REST API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public) requires oAuth authentication. So, you would have to provide access token with all of your API calls. oAuth specification allows you to get access token through javascript as well. So you might want to look into that.

If you decide on using REST API, I would suggest moving this to server-side. You would be able to save user tweet urls and data.

Alternatively, if you are just playing with javascript and want to do this for yourself, you can simply see in your browser's developer tools where official [Twitter widgets](https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-tweets) are getting tweet data and use that edges. I remember myself doing this several years ago.

But, please note. These urls are not public and official way of working with twitter data. So, they may change at any time and break your code.

Comment: Is there any simpler way becuase I want to do the same thing with instagram and facebook, like  a js function that does that?